# How to deal with rescinding acceptance of job offer at company B when company A countered?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, new-hires

I'm sure there are many opinion on this situation...

I recently accepted a job offer at company B, about a week ago. I went to resign at company A and they countered. At company A my role is currently ending, and company A says they have plans to transition me into another project. I knew about this, however I needed a change immediately and decided to accept another job offer. Well, when I tried to put in my two weeks, they countered with the same transition plan  this time faster and with more money and a career plan. Given the hideous amount of student loans I have I decided this is a much better offer, and I would like to stay. I requested they put it in a contract, and I am still waiting on the contract a week after I accepted an offer from company B.

Now I feel horrible for company B because I may be rescinding my acceptance about a week before my start date. Is it unprofessional to rescind a job offer acceptance?

Comment: You will burn a bridge, there's no getting around that.  It's not the most terrible thing to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Leaving a job very early to accept another offer](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7406/leaving-a-job-very-early-to-accept-another-offer)

Comment: Get this...Company A just lowered their counter today and changed the job title from what they told me they would promote me to. This definitely changes everything. Would you bail?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that you have the paperwork from A in hand, and notify B ASAP. Thank them for their time and state that you would have gone with B if A hadn't pulled all the stops and quickly made you a very strong offer. Apologize for any inconvenience and express the hope that you and company B wil be talking at some point in the future, because your interview experience with Company B gave you a strong, good impression of Company B.

Don't worry too much about company B - they'll just get the next candidate on their list. It's much better for Company B that you decline before your official start date than you show up and give your resignation in person on the day you start. And showing up on the day you start to hand in your resignation might be more than a little awkward for you. And you'll more likely than not look like a jerk.

As your last of piece of unfinished business, make a point of thanking the person who referred you to Company B. Yes, you decided to stay with A but thanks to that person, you got to know Company B and Company B is indeed a good company :)

Comment: Thanks, this is really comforting and helpful. I just hate to leave company B in the dirt like that, because I really did seriously consider them. I am definitely waiting on the paperwork from A so I am sure this is going to happen.

Comment: @Siah The minute you get that paperwork from A and kick it in, zoom an email to B. Don't string B along a minute more than necessary.

Comment: @Siah it's very likely company B won't consider you in the future over this, but if you follow Vietnhi's advice you at least make it possible they might consider you in the future. (Really depends on their hiring process and the personalities of those involved)

Comment: Yeah I really liked them as a company and the team seemed to be great. I will definitely emphasize that they left a lasting impression on me.

Comment: Get this...Company A just lowered their counter today and changed the job title from what they told me they would promote me to. This definitely changes everything. Would you bail?

Comment: Actions talk louder than words. And A's actions were real loud. You have a pretty good idea as to what I would do. Now, it's up to you to use your judgement and decide how you want to react. The people at B like you. You like them. Maybe it's time that you take a chance on each other. If you decide to leave A,just leave - no anger,no regrets, no recriminations. If A tries to put a guilt trip on you or bait you into a dispute, don't fall for the bait - What's important stuff is that you're out of here. They can keep their whining and their recriminations.