# Is it a good idea to point to the person that referred you after you decline an offer?

Tags: job-offer

I just read this in [an answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/36243/29610):

> As your last of piece of unfinished business, make a point of thanking the person who referred you to Company B. Yes, you decided to stay with A but thanks to that person, you got to know Company B and Company B is indeed a good company :)

Wouldn't that cause problems for the referring person? Maybe they already forgot how you got there, but this will remind them that Joe brought in this unreliable person that cancels a contract.

Comment: That thank you note was meant to be written directly to the person who referred the asker to B, pal. As for your use of the word "unreliable" to refere to the asker, I'll ignore it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand the confusion.

If Joe referred you to Company B, extend your thanks to Joe for the referral.  Joe did you a favor, thanking him for doing you a favor is a good thing to do.  This should be a person-to-person thanks.

I'm not sure who the "them" in "will remind them that Joe" refers to.  The suggestion was not to, say, email the hiring manager you've turned down and extend your thanks to Joe in that email.  No one other than Joe needs to see your thanks.

Comment: Oups, I read it as: I'm declining your offer, thank you for your time. I would also like to thank Joe for referring me to the company.

Comment: Not sure it counts as answering the question, but I'll accept anyway for clearing things up, thanks!