# Should I accept a job that I will quit in the near future?

Tags: job-offer

Similar to [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7406/leaving-a-job-very-early-to-accept-another-offer), albeit slightly different.

Long story short, I recently got a job and am supposed to start in the coming two days. However, I'm not really happy about the role and am still talking with others. Therefore, I'd most likely jump ship the first opportunity that I get, be it one week, one month, or one years. Also worth mentioning is that I have plenty of savings(1+ year) and have been unemployed for 4 months. I also have a side-business that brings in a negligable amount of money, so I can always point to that as being "what I was doing while I was unemployed."

Question: Should I accept a job that you know you will quit in the near future?

The one caveat is that I have a felony on my record. With current EEOC guideline and state regulations, I don't expect it to be a huge hindrance, but I have to be conscious of this also.

Comment: We can't tell you whether or not to take a job, but it is almost always better to wait to quit until you have a job in hand.

Comment: hello, consider [edit]ing the question to make it better fit site topics laid out in [help/on-topic]. In particular, [this guidance](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2695) may help to learn what is expected of questions here. Good luck!

Comment: describe how it is different.

Comment: @crh225 Presumably the difference is that OP hasn't started working for his new employer yet. That said, 2 days is very late in the process to be significantly different from leaving 2 weeks in.

Comment: Are the other people you're "talking" to about this interested in hiring someone who leaves after a few weeks?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you already accepted the position.

If you're certain it's what you want to do, resigning before you start the job is probably your best action. Alternatively, you could try to delay your start date until you hear from the other positions.

But will quitting shortly after you start this job make you look bad? Possibly. You might run the risk of burning bridges with this employer and [damaging your professional reputation](http://www.moneycrashers.com/quitting-new-job-better-offer/). It's also worth noting that it's usually [easier to get a job if you already have one](http://content.time.com/time/nation/article/0,8599,2073520-1,00.html).

You say you aren't happy about the role, but most people find it difficult to make those judgments until they're actually doing the job. It might turn out to be a great position.

With all that said, there are legitimate reasons to quit before or soon after you begin work (health, personal safety, building your own business, etc). If you are truly in that position, and it sounds like you at least have a side business to rely on, [resign as professionally as possible](http://money.usnews.com/money/careers/slideshows/how-to-quit-your-job-like-a-class-act).

Answer (score 3):

> Question: Should I accept a job that you know you will quit in the
>   near future?

I wouldn't.

For me, my word is my bond. When I accept a job, I accept it for the long-term with the expectation that I will be around until circumstances change dramatically. I would never accept a job that I knew wasn't going to last for a reasonable period of time.

Clearly you know that the employer wouldn't hire you if you made your intentions known, so this simply comes down to what kind of person do you want to be. I know what I would do, but your mileage may vary.

You are still talking with other potential employers, you indicate that you don't need the money, so I don't really understand why you are even entertaining the thought of accepting this job and then quitting it soon.

I never advise people to lie to employers or potential employers. To me, you are essentially lying to this employer. And unless you are willing to come clean to your next employer about why you are leaving so soon, you'll essentially be lying to the next employer as well. That's not a great trait to have in your work history, and never something I'd advise someone to do.

Comment: I feel similarly - but I can't honestly say that I would still feel the same way if I had been unemployed for four months. Even if I had savings to live on, I gotta say, that situation would be a strong incentive to take an imperfect job to pay the bills, in the full knowledge that I'd be keeping an eye out for something better.