# How do you leave a company after a short period having taken all vacation time?

Tags: resignation

I'm a software engineer and I've been working at my current company about 6 months now. This is also my first job out of college and I'm only 21 years old. A friend of mine notified me that a person at his company is leaving the company and there is now a position open. Next week I'll be leaving to Germany for a vacation that I've been planning since last year, one that will take all of my vacation time: 2 weeks.

I like my current company, but it wasn't exactly what I wanted to do. My friend's company is much more in line with what I like to do, and I would be happier there and likely earn more money as well. I would burn a bridge with this company however if I left, after only 6 months and with all of my vacation time used. How would this affect my reputation and is there anyway to resign without burning a bridge with this company?

Comment: Unfortunately, "what should I do" posts are off-topic here, since solutions to unique situations typically aren't helpful to anyone but the original poster.

Comment: Ah okay. I should have figured. I wonder if my question, if worded differently and more generically, would be accepted? Is there anyway to ask this question without being off topic?

Comment: @Austinh1 Check out [this meta post](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2693/custom-off-topic-close-reasons-change/2695#2695) on this specific close reason, which might help you understand how to edit your question.

Comment: Also, we have a very good question on [How to resign from a new job gracefully](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7149/how-can-one-resign-from-a-new-job-gracefully). That question, and [this one as well](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7406/leaving-a-job-very-early-to-accept-another-offer), may help answer the question you're really struggling with.

Comment: Okay, I will check those questions out. Thanks for your help. I also edited the question to hopefully be on topic, but if it's decided to be off-topic that's okay too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What will happen about your vacation will depend on your employer's policy. In America most employers will not let you take vacation unless you have already accrued the time. Others may allow you to borrow time un-earned and get it back through the rest of the year. If you have borrowed vacation time it will have to be payed back (it will be removed from your last pay check). Eg. If you worked 6 months and you annual allowance is 2 weeks then you will have earned one week and owe one week back. So in your last pay check they will deduct a week's salary (exact details you should find in your employee handbook).

I would not worry about burning bridges (as long as you give notice). Its not a personal thing and you are a junior employee so there should be no critical projects that depend on your exclusive input (In two years nobody will even remember you worked there :-) ).

So if you will be happier get payed more I would make the jump.

Answer (score 2):

What will most likely happen is that if you leave your job before you're worked a full year, but take your full vacation, the company will dock your pay for the vacation days you haven't yet "earned".

At the end of the day if the other job is a better fit you should simply take it. Will your current employer be happy? No.

However, if it was in the company's interest to fire you - regardless of the implication to yourself - you would be fired and told to clean your desk out the same day with no second though given to your well-being.

So what I'm advising you is to keep your own best interests in mind.

Comment: @Joe Strazzere - I edited it to better express my point

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I guess what he's trying to say is that the company isn't loyal to you so having a sense of loyalty shouldn't be a driving factor in his decision since it would not work the other way. Whether that is a valid viewpoint is another discussion.