# How to quit after a month when there is nothing wrong with the job or my performance

Tags: resignation

I started a really good job 3weeks ago, I am actually very good at what I am doing here and have made an impact. There is nothing wrong with the role, it's as I expected, in fact much more high profile which is good.

The problem is I just had an offer for another job with a great company, more money and better future prospects and I have accepted the offer after careful consideration (there was no contest really other than me only being in a job for 3 weeks!).

I am now wondering how to tell my manager, I know they have struggled to fill the role as they were looking for the "right person" and I have also been introduced to most of the leadership team I will be working with.
How do I explain to my manager and to everyone else who I have met? I know it's only business but I am gutted for my manager (he is a nice guy and the company seems really good too, just that I have always wanted to work for the other company and I have better future prospects there too so not just about the money).

FWIW I have a 4 weeks notice period.

Please advise, I have to do it as soon as my manager is back from holiday in a couple of days...

Comment: Hi Boss, this isn't working out for me.  Here's my 2 week notice...

Comment: @TheWanderingDevManager not sure, whereas both questions are about quitting a job early on, the other specifically mention intrinsic issues with the given job. Here the OP only wants to leave *because* of another job. Meaning that the accepted answer from the other question cannot be used exactly here.

Comment: Yes @bilbo I agree my situation is very different, there are no issues with the job, it would be a lie to say there was so I can't use that, I enjoy what I do & I am good at it too. It's just that I finished the interview process for the other role before I started here but because of holidays etc I only just found after I started here and the role has better future prospects, more money too although this is not the huge driver. Thanks

Comment: Then duplicate of : http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/7406/16

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Your post is even-handed, polite, and complimentary to your current boss and team members, and your motivation is clear. Send an email to your boss with a link to this question, and say, "I wrote this."

Comment: I don't think it's ever a good idea to show an employer a random post on the internet you made about their company. Especially since this person likes the company, he should at least tell them in person.

Comment: Print this page out and bring it to his office then. Or write it on a card. Whatever. The point is that the question clearly articulates Mi.sst's reasoning for the resignation and avoids any negative attribution. Everything s/he needs to say/write/email is already in the question.