# joining a different company after accepting an offer

Tags: job-offer

I had an offer with company A but was in recruitment process with company B who also made me an offer that I accepted with a joining date several months ahead. I ended up joining company A nevertheless and now I want to quit company A and join company B. The problem is that I did not tell company B that I joined company A in the interval and now I don't feel comfortable joining without disclosing that to them. What would you do ?
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Leaving a job very early to accept another offer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7406/leaving-a-job-very-early-to-accept-another-offer)

Comment: You'll have to be a bit more explicit with timelines

Comment: joined company A in May, one week after accepting offer of company B to start with company B in September.

Comment: Information on the comments on the answers seems inconsistent with what's presented above. Was OP actively searching for a job and accepted company B with a several months future start date, then accepted and onboarded at company A? Or was OP "planning to leave company A and take some time off for personal reasons" and pushed back the start day at company B by "6 weeks"? This situation was presented just as unclearly as it was handled.

Comment: Is there any chance that if you can join company B now, then a few weeks later, you may want to go back to company A again ?

Answer (score 2):

#### You made this bed hard now try to sleep in it.

You were working at A when you took the job at B,  then asked B to push back your start date several months for "personal" reasons, when the personal reasons were you already accepted another job.  What you have done is tried to poison the well at both companies [it's metaphor day apparently].

You aren't comfortable joining without disclosing this because you know it was squirrelly.  My advice, keep this silliness to yourself, hope B doesn't find out, and try to act right in the future.

Comment: I know it is a tricky situation and that's why I am asking. I did not push back the starting date by several months but by 6 weeks. The options I have now are: option 1 I don't join company B (I feel bad about that because I wouldn't honor my word), option 2 full disclosure at the risk of company B refusing to take me in (I am willing to take that risk), option 3 hope B doesn't find out (I don't like that, it's not honest. I want work for company knowing I am hiding something, very unprofessional and unethical). It's kind messy and I feel really bad about it.

Comment: You talk about honoring your word, being honest, being ethical, etc. but unless I'm misunderstanding things it looks like personal integrity is something you're a bit lacking in.

Comment: Yes I pushed back the joining date at company B

Answer (score -1):

Why would you need to tell Company B that you joined Company A? Why would it be any concern of theirs? Why would they care? What you did isn't illegal, immoral, or unethical. Did Company B think you weren't going to work while waiting to join them? Did they think that you're independently wealthy and don't need to work to pay bills?

You don't need to tell them, and shouldn't.

Comment: The thing is I had to ask company B to push back the joining date personal and family reasons.

Comment: Yes I am planning to leave company A and take some time off for personal reasons that is why I am pushing back.

Comment: OK, well... you didn't put that information in your question, which changes the entire perspective.